# System.StringException: Invalid id: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

Tags: apex, invalid

I'm getting this error "System.StringException: Invalid id: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record" occasionally from one of my batch job.

Below is the error.

```
     Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 
         005i00000033wUw/00Di0000000cf1i

      Failed to process batch for class 'CopyClaimInspecStagToClaimInvBatch' 
         for job id '7071Y000091qlSe'

      caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: unable to obtain 
         exclusive access to this record

      External entry point
      Class.CopyClaimInspecStagToClaimInvBatch.execute: line 52, column 1
```

and below is the code which throws the error.

```
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
      List<Claim_Inspection_Staging__c> scope)
      {    
       new ClaimInspectionStagingTriggerHandler().copyToClaimInventory(scope,BC.getJobId());
}
```

Any idea why this error occurring and why it is happening only occasionally?

Any ideas/comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks...!

Comment: Is it possible that someone deleted the record while it was being processed by the batch?

Comment: Hi Sudh, could you please include code and errors as text in the body of your post, rather than screenshots? You can use the buttons at the top of the editor to format them as code and quoted text respectively.

Comment: @DavidRedd - I added code segments as inline.